# How to run bonnmotion in one simulator?

Tags: one-simulator

how to convert bonnmotion using perl? And how to run bonnmotion in one simulator? I have tried but it failed. please explain to me the steps in full. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The latest [BonnMotion](https://sys.cs.uos.de/bonnmotion/index.shtml) seems to have option to generate ONE simulator traces directly, without the need to use the Perl script (see the [BonnMotion documentation](https://sys.cs.uos.de/bonnmotion/doc/README.pdf) section 7.7 for details).